# Are re-invested dividends taxable in the UK?

Tags: taxes, investing, united-kingdom, etf, mutual-funds

Let's suppose that you invest in an accumulation ETF/mutual fund, whose automatically re-invest dividends.

In such case, those dividends should not be taxable since you actually never receive them. However, I have read that these dividends are not-taxable **only** if your brokerage firm doesn't provide you the option of distributing them. Let me explain:

Let's suppose there is brokerage firm that offers an ETF and the investor can choose if the dividends are directly reinvested or, conversely, distributed. In such case, even if you choose to re-invest dividends, they are taxable. Is this true?

Does this apply for different ETFs? That is, let's suppose that a brokerage firm offers exactly the same ETF but in two different versions, distribution (don't reinvest dividends) and accumulation (reinvest dividends), and an investor choose the accumulation one. Are those non-distributed dividends taxable?

Comment: Do you have any reference for the idea that they aren't taxable if there's no option to distribute them? I found several references that confirm what the existing answer indicates, that they are always taxable as income tax (but then don't count for CGT when you sell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Companies pay corporation tax on dividends before the ETF receives them so whether the ETF/brokerage pays the dividend to you or reinvests it, that tax has already been paid.

If the dividend is paid to you and the ETF is

- part of your pension, you pay income tax on it when you spend it
- part of an ISA, no tax is due
- [dividend tax is due whether or not the dividend is reinvested](https://www.justetf.com/uk/news/etf/distributing-or-accumulating-etfs-how-to-handle-investment-income.html). [Dividend tax is always due at your highest tax band](https://www.informdirect.co.uk/shares/dividend-tax-and-basic-rate-taxpayers/), although there is a [dividend allowance](https://www.barclays.co.uk/smart-investor/news-and-research/investing-for-beginners/should-you-reinvest-income/) that varies depending on your income tax band.
  Dividends above the dividend tax threshold of £2,000 are subject to tax at [7.5% for basic rate taxpayers, rising to 32.5% and 38.1% respectively for higher rate and additional-rate taxpayers](https://www.gov.uk/tax-on-dividends).

If you could escape tax by reinvesting your dividends then everyone would do so and then simply pay out of the fund capital at a slightly later date if they needed to.

If shares are not held in a pension or an ISA then capital gains tax (CGT) is liable when they are sold. Again there's a capital gains tax allowance, which for the 2020-21 tax year is £12,300.

CGT will be payable on the value of the investment when it's sold, minus the original investment and any income you’ve reinvested.

Thanks to timday for the ETF taxation link.

Comment: I think the above is misleading: on unsheltered (non-SIPP, non-ISA) holdings, income tax *is* due on the dividend income retained and reinvested by accumulating ETF units.  See e.g the "You still pay tax on accumulating ETFs" section of this article: https://www.justetf.com/uk/news/etf/distributing-or-accumulating-etfs-how-to-handle-investment-income.html .  So far as HMRC is concerned the income is still there, even if you didn't take it, and it needs to be taxed accordingly.  Personally I avoid accumulating funds/ETFs outside of ISA/SIPP wrappers; it makes the record-keeping simpler.

Comment: Isn't the final point precisely what the question is about - i.e. what counts as "receiving the dividend", when you aren't using a wrapper with tax-exempt growth.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Well that makes no difference and I've added a link to show that. The whole tax situation for non-ISA non-pension investments is complicated with several types of tax due. Hopefully I've covered it all in enough detail now.

Comment: @RobertLongson your link refers to US tax law, unless I've misunderstood. I think most of what you've said is tangential to the specific issue raised in the question - namely whether it makes a difference if you have the option to receive the dividend or not.

Comment: I can't find anything definitive, like HMRC guidance that specifically refers to ETFs, but the equivalent manual for unit trusts confirms what you say: https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg57707

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I've found a non-US link. It's from a specific company (BAT) but the infomation would be true for all companies.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think that one is about an individual shareholding, rather than an ETF. Maybe the same rules apply. but I'm not sure.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica If the same rules didn't apply everyone would just reinvest dividends and then convert that to cash the next day. Also the uk government's site would need to say the rules didn't apply. It's hard to demonstrate something doesn't apply though because the government simply says when taxes are applied, not when they aren't.

Comment: That BAT DRIP page is another example of the general principle of not being able to pretend income is something else (capital gains) by reinvesting it. Seems a bit of an odd thing to link to when there are other things which explain it better though: the info at https://www.justetf.com/uk/news/etf/distributing-or-accumulating-etfs-how-to-handle-investment-income.html page is unequivocally about accumulating ETFs, and there's a great Monevator article on OEIC fund ACC unit taxation (but which also applies to ETFs; they're fund units too) at https://monevator.com/income-tax-on-accumulation-unit/

Comment: @timday thank you for the link I've updated the answer, replaced the link and credited you with providing it.